# Android: Button with Ripple and State Selector in Background: Resource Not Found Exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, rippledrawable

I have a button with a ripple effect and would like to add a state selector for the background color when the button is enabled/disabled.

state_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/green" android:state_enabled="true"/>

    <item android:color="@color/grey" android:state_enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

ripple.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight"> 
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask" android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/state_selector" />

</ripple>
```

Button.xml:

```
<Button
        android:background="@drawable/ripple"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
```

But the app crashes while rendering this with the following:

```
Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable drawable/ripple with resource ID #0x7f070071
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ripple.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070071
```

and

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable drawable/state_selector with resource ID #0x7f070075
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/state_selector.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070075
```

could someone please help figure out the issue?
thanks

Comment: what's your min sdk ?

Comment: 23. Ripple is supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

The ripple  needs a drawable resource.

The state selector which I had used did not provide a drawable for each state but rather it provided a color for each state. And thus it was crashing.

The following xml for the state selector would fix this issue. Everything else remains the same.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_enabled="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@color/grey" android:state_enabled="false"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 6):

I think @Sunny's answer works well.

This suggestion may be overkill but you can also combine the ripple and selector into a single xml file like this. This is a rounded transparent button with a ripple and an enabled and disabled state.

button_transparent_background.xml

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/white">

    <item>
        <selector>
            <item android:state_enabled="true">
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="@color/white" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:state_enabled="false">
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
                    <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="@color/whiteTransparent" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</ripple>
```

Add it to the button's background property or to the styles.xml

```
<style name="buttonRound" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_transparent_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: Finally a version that works. The second item beneath the selector item made it work. Thanks!